# Currency pair Powerset In itertools with constraints

Tags: python, python-itertools, cryptocurrency

I have determined that what I’m looking to accomplish is to generate a powerset, and it seems that itertools could help me accomplish it, but I need to apply a number of rules to constrain the results.

I’m wanting to combine currencies, but they come in currency pairs, which means that not all possible combinations or sequences are possible.

Sample set of currencies:
BTC, ETH, USD, EOS, XRP, IOT

Relevant currency pairs:
ETH-BTC, ETH-USD, EOS-ETH, IOT-ETH, BTC-USD, EOS-BTC, XRP-BTC, IOT-BTC, EOS-USD, XRP-USD, IOT-USD

Rules:
Adjacent currencies in the sequence must be valid pairs, and first and last currencies in the sequence must also be valid pairs. The order of the pairs is irrelevant (BTC-USD ≡ USD-BTC). Examples of valid and invalid sequences:
- Valid: {BTC, USD, EOS, ETH} is a valid sequence because BTC-USD, EOS-USD, EOS-ETH, and ETH-BTC are valid pairs
- Invalid: {BTC, USD, IOT, XRP} is not a valid sequence because IOT-XRP is not a valid pair
- Invalid: {EOS, BTC, USD, IOT} is not a valid sequence because the first and last currencies (EOS-IOT) do not form a valid pair.

Also, although a powerset is technically combinations of any length, the minimum sequence length must be three, e.g. {ETH, BTC, USD}, with no maximum length.

Thanks in advance! I’ve been turning my brain into mush on this.

Comment: I wouldn't frame this in terms of power sets. Sets are inherently unordered, whereas your problem has clear sequential structure to it.

Comment: It looks like a simple bidirectional graph would suffice here. Could you show some of the (presumably unsuccessful) ideas that you've run through so far?

Comment: Take a look at the networkx library. Your currencies are nodes and the pairs are edges. There are lots of traversal algorithms you could use.

Comment: Responding to @NPE, I guess I saw it as sort of filtering the results, since the set I’m looking for is a subset of what a powerset would produce.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I was looking into graph databases with the concept of currencies as nodes and pairs as edges earlier this evening. More specifically, in a currency pair, there’s a “base” currency and a “quote” currency which I was thinking of as attributes or directionality in the edges. Haven’t found any examples of anyone else doing it yet though. I’ll look into networkx